# Propagate dd changes to filesystem top layer

Tags: linux, filesystems, dd

I have several different filesystems in .img files that are mounted and I want to access them in two ways: one being the usual graphical file explorer, adding and removing files and folders and changing their content using the normal applications, while the other is through the command line tool **dd** directly to the .img file.

Here's the script that I am running:

```
fallocate -l 32M fat32.img
mkfs -t vfat fat32.img
sudo mount -t vfat -w -o loop fat32.img /media/fat32
```

After this, changes using the file explorer are, eventually, propagated to the .img file content (but not instantaneously), but the opposite doesn't happend. How can I disable or flush caches in order to force this update (both ways)?

I use this command to perform the dd

```
dd of=fat32.img oflag=sync conv=notrunc,fsync seek=86660 bs=1 count=5
```

I'm not handling collisions between the changes made by the file explorer and **dd** right now.

Answer (score 1):

After you make a change, run `sync`.

Comment: have the same effect. the only way I can make this work it's to unmount before I make the changes, which it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Is this ext4 (check /etc/fstab and /proc/mounts for some info)?  You might try setting the sync and/or commit=0 options on the filesystem itself.